# What's the meaning of chained template parameters declarations?

Tags: scala

I have just stumbled upon code like this in Scala and don't understand the meaning of it:

```
def combineByFrame[RX: ST: ORD, CX: ST: ORD, CXX: ST: ORD, T: ST: NUM: TypeTag](inputFrame: Frame[RX, CX, T], combineFrame: Frame[RX, CX, CXX], combineClosure: Function1[Vec[T], T]): Frame[RX, CXX, T] = {
   // ...
}
```

What I don't understand is the chained template declarations like the following `RX: ST: ORD`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is type class notation.  `def foo[A: B](a: A)` is short for

```
def foo[A, B[A]](a: A)(implicit b_evidence: B[A])
```

and it means that there is some `B` thing that knows something about `A`.  If you have more than one, you can chain them with colons (ugly, I know).

So, `T: ST: NUM: TypeTag` means that generic type `T` must have some implicit (filled with either an `implicit val` or an `implicit def` somewhere in scope) of type `ST[T]` and another of type `NUM[T]` and another of type `TypeTag[T]`.  The last of these, for example, provides various type-level operations for `T`.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer ... could you throw in a small example to grasp the idea and also improve the quality of the answer? Would be most welcome.

Comment: @GiovanniAzua - Someone else is welcome to, but the time required is more than I have presently.